# Django model column

Tags: python, django

How I can make a model field to return a default value from function?

```
class Q(models.Model):
    _random_id = models.CharField(max_length=18)

    @property
    def random_id(self):
        return self._random_id

    @random_id.setter
    def random_id(self):
        self._random_id = f()
```

Comment: there is the `default` field option.  Each model will automatically have an `id` field that is unique for that model.. you

Comment: yeah but i need to add value from function f() as default

Comment: You can override your save mathod and if the record is new you can have random_id set to `f()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for `default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default):

> This can be a value or a callable object. If callable it will be called every time a new object is created.

So, you can pass it a function:

```
_random_id = models.CharField(max_length=18, default=f)
```

`Q` is the name of a built-in in django, so its best not to use it for your model.

Further,

```
@property
def random_id(self):
    return self._random_id
```

This is only serving as syntactical sugar because you can refer to the `_random_id` field directly from an instance of the model:

```
foo = Q()
foo._random_id
```

So you should consider removing this property entirely; and if you need `random_id`, set it as the name of your field.